# Group by date and count specific values in Python

Tags: python, count

I want to count how many files are produced per day. I have the code to output the files but i don't know what to use to group the files by date and count them.

How do i do this ?

```
import xlwt
import os
import datetime

now = datetime.date.today()



extension = '.txt'

envs = ['<foldername>']



for env in envs:
    file_path = '\\<servername>\<folder>\' + env + '\<folder>\'
    for files in os.listdir(file_path):
        list = []
        list.append(os.path.getmtime(file_path+files))
        for list_code_date in list:
            listt=[]
            listt.append(datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(list_code_date).strftime('%d-%m-%Y'))
        for list_hn_date in listt:
            print list_hn_date
```

Comment: Have you tried loading your data into a pandas DataFrame? There's a built-in function `groupby()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used os.popen instead as i was using to much code originally for a simple task:

```
dates = os.popen('cmd /c "cd /d R:\\'+env+'\\Crash_Reports && C:\\cygwin64\\bin\\find_linux.exe . -type f -printf "%TY-%Tm-%Td\\n" | sort |C:\\cygwin64\\bin\\uniq -c | C:\\cygwin64\\bin\\gawk "{print $2}""').read()
```